# ODBC Error in sql query

Tags: ms-access

I'm working with classic ASP, that's the error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'

[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '1 LIMIT 1'.
```

The query is:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM prezzi LIMIT 15 ORDER BY posizione"
```

Without LIMIT 15 it works but I need to paginate all the results.

What's wrong?

Comment: Access Driver - MySQL DB tag - Limit is a MySQL construct, not an access one - so exactly which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using ADODB connected with an Access MDB

Comment: In MYSQL, LIMIT clause should go **after** ORDER BY clause, not before : `SELECT * FROM prezzi  ORDER BY posizione  LIMIT 15`. If the DB is Access, you should use TOP instead of LIMIT:  `SELECT TOP 15 * FROM prezzi  ORDER BY posizione `

Answer (score 1):

If the database is Access as you indicate then the query would be :

```
SELECT TOP 15 * FROM prezzi ORDER BY posizione
```

Limit is a MySQL construct, not an Access one.

Comment: How can I limit in access?

Comment: That's what TOP does.